# Spring boot data rest - @RestResource(exported = false) not working with inherited methods. (save, delete)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I'm facing the issue that when annotating inherited methods (inherited by CRUDRepository, PagingAndSortingRepository) with @RestResource(exported = false), they will still be available.
When doing the same thing with a non-inherited method, it will correctly be removed. I'm checking via Swagger whether a method is available.

I've set the detection strategy to 'annotated' in the application.properties file.

```
spring.data.rest.detection-strategy=annotated
```

Here's an example of what i have configured:

```java
package com.campusplusplus.entity.repository;

import com.campusplusplus.entity.model.Curriculum;
import com.campusplusplus.entity.model.Lecture;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RestResource;


// https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.4.1/reference/html/#reference
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "lectures", path = "lectures")
public interface LectureRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Lecture, Long> {

    /*
    These are not removed
     */
    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    void delete(Lecture lecture);

    /*
    These are not removed
     */
    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    void deleteById(Long aLong);

    Lecture findByLectureName(String lectureName);

    Lecture findByCurriculumAndLectureName(Curriculum curriculum, String lectureName);

    /*
    This one is correctly removed
    */
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    void deleteByLectureId(Long lectureId);

}
```

In addition to using the data-rest provided methods, i have RestController configured, which are annotated in the following way, they also appear on Swagger, so this seems to be fine.

```java
package com.campusplusplus.rest.controller;

import com.campusplusplus.entity.controller.CurriculumDbController;
import com.campusplusplus.entity.controller.LectureDbController;
import com.campusplusplus.entity.model.Curriculum;
import com.campusplusplus.entity.model.Lecture;
import com.campusplusplus.exceptions.CurriculumNotFoundException;
import com.campusplusplus.exceptions.LectureDuplicateException;
import com.campusplusplus.exceptions.LectureNotFoundException;
import com.campusplusplus.rest.dto.LectureDto;
import com.campusplusplus.rest.mapper.LectureMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestController;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/lectures")
public class LectureRestController {

    private final CurriculumDbController curriculumDbController;
    private final LectureDbController lectureDbController;
    private final LectureMapper lectureMapper;
    private final FileRestController fileRestController;

    @Autowired
    public LectureRestController(CurriculumDbController curriculumDbController, LectureDbController lectureDbController, LectureMapper lectureMapper, FileRestController fileRestController) {
        this.curriculumDbController = curriculumDbController;
        this.lectureDbController = lectureDbController;
        this.lectureMapper = lectureMapper;
        this.fileRestController = fileRestController;
    }

/*
    Create new lecture
 */

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Object> createLecture(@RequestBody LectureDto lectureDto) {

        Curriculum curriculum = verifyCurriculumExists(lectureDto.getCurriculumId());
        Lecture lecture = lectureMapper.toModel(lectureDto);
        verifyLectureUniqueness(lecture);

        lectureDbController.save(lecture);
        lecture.setUrlPath("/lectures/" + lecture.getLectureId());
        curriculum.addLecture(lecture);
        curriculumDbController.save(curriculum);

        return ResponseEntity.created(URI.create(lecture.getUrlPath())).build();

    }

    /*
        Update existing lecture
     */

    @PutMapping(value = "/{lectureId:.+}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> updateLecture(@RequestBody LectureDto lectureDto, @PathVariable Long lectureId) {

        verifyLectureExists(lectureId);
        verifyCurriculumExists(lectureDto.getCurriculumId());
        Lecture existingLecture = lectureDbController.findById(lectureId);
        Lecture updatedLecture = lectureMapper.toModel(lectureDto);

        verifyLectureUniqueness(updatedLecture);
        existingLecture.copyFrom(updatedLecture);
        Lecture savedLecture = lectureDbController.save(existingLecture);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(savedLecture);

    }

    /*
        Delete specific lecture, also deletes all
     */

    @DeleteMapping(value = "/{lectureId:.+}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> deleteLecture(@PathVariable Long lectureId) {

        deleteLectureHelper(lectureId);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

    public void deleteLectureHelper(Long lectureId) {

        Lecture lecture = verifyLectureExists(lectureId);
        lecture.getFiles().forEach(file -> {
            try {
                fileRestController.deleteFile(file.getAlteredName());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        lectureDbController.deleteByLectureId(lectureId);
    }


    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getAllLectures() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(lectureDbController.findAll());
    }
    

    private Lecture verifyLectureExists(Long lectureId) {
        Lecture lecture = lectureDbController.findById(lectureId);
        if (lecture == null) {
            throw new LectureNotFoundException("Lecture not found: " + lectureId);
        }
        return lecture;
    }

    private Curriculum verifyCurriculumExists(Long curriculumId) {
        Curriculum curriculum = curriculumDbController.findById(curriculumId);
        if (curriculum == null) {
            throw new CurriculumNotFoundException("Curriculum not found: " + curriculumId);
        }
        return curriculum;
    }

    private void verifyLectureUniqueness(Lecture lecture) {

        if (lectureDbController.findByCurriculumAndLectureName(lecture.getCurriculum(), lecture.getLectureName()) != null) {
            throw new LectureDuplicateException("Duplicate lecture: " + lecture.getLectureName());
        }

    }

    @ExceptionHandler(CurriculumNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleCurriculumNotFoundException(CurriculumNotFoundException exc) {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(LectureDuplicateException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleLectureDuplicateException(LectureDuplicateException exc) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(LectureNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleLectureNotFoundException(LectureNotFoundException exc) {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }


}
```

Dependency-wise, everything should be up to date:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->

    </parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>campusplusplus</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>campusplusplus</name>
    <description>CampusPlusPlus Backend</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--        <dependency>-->
        <!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>-->
        <!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- TEMPORARY FOR INITIAL TESTS, REMOVE ONCE POSTGRES IS AVAILABLE-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.200</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--         https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--        <dependency>-->
        <!--            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>-->
        <!--            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>-->
        <!--        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2020.0.1</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <!--    <dependencyManagement>-->
    <!--        <dependencies>-->
    <!--            <dependency>-->
    <!--                <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>-->
    <!--                <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>-->
    <!--                <version>11.0.2</version>-->
    <!--                <type>pom</type>-->
    <!--                <scope>import</scope>-->
    <!--            </dependency>-->
    <!--        </dependencies>-->
    <!--    </dependencyManagement>-->


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>15</source>
                    <target>15</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Although i'm not sure if it is of importance, I'm also adding the Lecture object:

```java
package com.campusplusplus.entity.model;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "lectures", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"lectureName", "curriculum_curriculum_id"})})
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Lecture {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "lecture_id")
    private Long lectureId;
    private String lectureName;
    private Integer relativeSemester;
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    private Curriculum curriculum;
    private Long curriculumId;
    private String urlPath;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "lecture")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<File> files;

    public Lecture copyFrom(Lecture updatedLecture) {

        this.lectureName = updatedLecture.getLectureName();
        this.relativeSemester = updatedLecture.relativeSemester;
        this.curriculum = updatedLecture.curriculum;
        this.curriculumId = updatedLecture.curriculumId;
        this.urlPath = "/lectures/" + lectureId;
        return this;
    }
}
```

I've searched for hours and i keep finding the "exported = false" solution, which just won't work for me.

I've also tried point 5 of this article, which didn't have any effect:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-customize-http-endpoints

Does anyone have a suggestion on where I'm going in a wrong directions?

Thanks and best regards
Thomas

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.item-resource The documentation states that when you configure the endpoint with `@RestResource(exported = false)` the endpoint is not removed but rather returns status code 405 every time you call it. I guess there is no real method to completely remove that endpoint

Comment: @AmirSchnell, thank you, you're right. It does however remove the endpoint from swagger for methods i've written myself, so that is very curious.  
I did test it this before writing the post and it allowed me to delete a resource nonetheless, but in that case, it must have used the delete method in my controller.  
  
Thank you very much!